# model relationship and Queries in Django not a clear

Tags: django, model, relationship

what does these lines of code mean in Django View: i couldn't find a details explanation, I came to Django from a Laravel background, so I can understand the models and relationships... thanks

```
customer = request.user.customer
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
customer = request.user.customer
```

The request object has a user, the user is the authenticated user (if no user is authenticated then the `AnonymousUser` object is returned instead). In this example the `User` model (i.e. the user table) has a field called `customer` and we are accessing that field.

```py
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
```

Here we are simply querying the `Product` table for a specific product with the given `productId`. Note, Django will raise an error if two records are returned when you use the `.get()` method (i.e. if two rows in the `Product` table have the same `productId`.

```py
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
```

Next we use the `get_or_create()` method to look up an `order` based off of the `customer` (the value of which we extracted above`. If an order cannot be found we will create one instead. The value of` created`will be True if a new`order` was created or False if one already existed.

```py
orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
```

Just as above we are getting or creating an `OrderItem` using the `order` and `product` fields.

Comment: but if it does not exist, how we can create one instead? i mean where the data required to create order?, why do we add (created)? and can we replace it with any other string

Comment: Most of your questions are answered above. If order doesn't exist then it will be created when using `.get_or_create`. From the code it seems that only data required is `customer` (you get it from `request.user.customer`) and `complete` which is just boolean. We add `created` so we can check if order was created (then it's true) or retrived (then it's false)